# Update url with htaccess

Tags: php

I want to change the formatting of this URL:

```
~/index.php/user/category_grid/?id=4&name=%27Door%20Knobs%27
```

to

```
~/index.php/user/category_grid/4/Door Knob
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of Rewrite rule that would transform the URL

```
RewriteRule index.php/user/category_grid/([-\w]+)/([-\w]+)/?$   index.php/user/category_grid?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```